# Take - Haskell problems within lists

Tags: list, haskell, integral, take

I am in the process of learning Haskell. I have a function that looks as follows:

```
takeN :: Integral a => a -> [a]
takeN n = take n [x | x<-[0..]]
```

All I want this to do, is return n amount of elements in an infinite list, and I am unaware of why this is not working. Any explanations of how to fix it without abandoning my binding (?)

Comment: What error are you getting?  It worked for me.

Comment: Notice `takeN n = [0 .. n - 1]` also works and has the same meaning - the fact that `[0..]` is potentially infinite is immaterial.

Comment: @jamshidh Did you include the type signature?

Comment: @PyRulez - oddly enough, yes....  And it worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is that `take` has the type `Int -> [a] -> [a]`. The number must be an `Int`, and can't be any `Integral`.

You can address the issue with `fromIntegral`:

```
takeN :: Integral a => a -> [a]
takeN n = take (fromIntegral n) [x | x<-[0..]]
```

Comment: @Carsten I'm not sure what you mean... The above implementation works on my machine™.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without making your own function:
  input>>  take 3 [1..]
  output>> [1,2,3]